# If/Else Statement Assistance

Tags: javascript

I need to make this line of code into an If/Else statement for a school project and cannot figure out how to do so. The button currently triggers the picture to show on the page, but I cannot figure out how to also make it hide on button click using an If/Else statement.

```
$('#showA').on('click', function() {
    $('#house1').css('opacity', 1).fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

Comment: You set the opacity to one than fade in?

Comment: You know it is built into jQuery to toggle? http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No need a if/else** - just use with [`fadeToggle()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi52Nyy6MTTAhUJLY8KHYHMDtEQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffadetoggle%2F&usg=AFQjCNGGut_7zTAYCNe3tU9FHSAT9CiUHg&sig2=ADIKo6mbJ5e5gYVZw2jqqA) of `Jquery` function .

```
$('#showA').on('click', function() {
    $('#house1').fadeToggle('slow');
  });
```

***Refer the Demo snippet***

```js
 $('#showA').on('click', function() {
        $('#house1').fadeToggle('slow');
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="showA">show</p>
<h3 id="house1">hello</h3>
```

**Use with if/else** for OP required

1. adding the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` depend on `count` variable
2. if the element was hidden `count` reset to `0`
3. At the time of click `count == 0` element will be hidden

```js
var count=0;
$('#showA').on('click', function() {
           if(count == 0){
            $('#house1').fadeOut('400');
            count++
            }
            else {
            $('#house1').fadeIn('400');
            count=0
            }
          });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p id="showA">show</p>
    <h3 id="house1">hello</h3>
```

Comment: I didn't know fadeToggle was a function, thank you for that. But the professor is requiring me to use an If/Else statement for the project, that's the only reason I have to do it that way. I'm not too sure why she wants it that way but it is what it is. Do you think you can help me with that?

Comment: @kylebuzzy1 see the updated answer ..Its a if/else statement to solve your code

Answer (score 0):

There's a `jQuery` function responsible for it - `fadeToggle`.

**Note**: `fade` function already operates the `opacity` property, you don't need to include it.

```js
$('#showA').on('click', function() {
    $('#house1').fadeToggle('slow');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='showA'>click</button>
<p id='house1' hidden>Hi</p>
```